How to remove HTTP header from outgoing requests in c#
I have an API project in c# .net core 6 hosted in k8.
I have enabled new relic in my project and tracing each API request as below.
 Uri uri = new Uri($"{uriHostPath}inittrans");
 NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.SetTransactionUri(uri);

In my app i'm calling external SOAP services.
Now the problem is few of the external requests are getting failed due to timeout.
From external service point of view there is no problem in downstream soap service.
To debug timeout issue, we took the TCP dump of outgoing requests and found that there is a newrelic header getting added in each outgoing HTPP request with a big string value(base64 encodied string) which is causing the issue in network.
Sample TCP dump payload :
010.028.025.228.58658-202.043.122.108.00080: POST /ticketbook/clsBook.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: ****
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0
SOAPAction: "http://www.gtree.co.in/objExecute"

newrelic: eyJ2Ijpb..............OWUzNzlhYmNmNmUifX0=

traceparent: 00-1b88a00531a7f2a46b45236b531db35b-94a1c9e379abcf6e-01
tracestate: 206830@nr=0-0-206830-1078067976-94a1c9e379abcf6e-974e420a2ec4ad63-1-1.322319-1715076143685,
elastic-apm-traceparent: 00-ef11ab2c795d174b908650ea571bfd42-1b738c70ab52be49-00
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 447

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><objExecute xmlns="http://www.gtree.co.in" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><strCommand>GETDATA</strCommand><strParam1>123</strParam1><strParam2/><strParam3/><strParam4/><strParam5/><strParam6/><strParam7/><strParam8/><strParam9/><strParam10/><strParam11/><strParam12/><strParam13/><strParam14/><strParam15/></objExecute></s:Body></s:Envelope>
********: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 537
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 07 May 2024 10:00:41 GMT

After this we disabled new relic agent in our app and then issue got resolved.
We don't want to stop monitoring for our app, hence removing newrelic agent was the temporary solution that worked for us.
I tried to remove newrelic header from outgoing HTTP requests with the help of code  with CustomEndpointBehaviour class but this didnt work too.
    public class CustomEndpointBehaviour : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        private readonly Func<HttpMessageHandler> _httpMessageHandler;

        public CustomEndpointBehaviour(IHttpMessageHandlerFactory factory)
        {
            // Here we prescribe how handler will be created.
            // Since it uses IHttpMessageHandlerFactory, this factory will manage the setup and lifetime of the handler, 
            // based on the configuration we provided with AddHttpClient(serviceName) 
            _httpMessageHandler = () => factory.CreateHandler();
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            // We need this line to add our HttpMessageHandler as HttpClientHandler.
            bindingParameters?.Add(new Func<HttpClientHandler, HttpMessageHandler>(handler => _httpMessageHandler()));
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            // Add custom message inspector to remove New Relic header
            clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }

    }

    public class CustomMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            // Find and remove the New Relic header
            var headers = request.Headers;
            if (headers.FindHeader("newrelic", "") != -1)
            {
                headers.RemoveAt(headers.FindHeader("newrelic", ""));
            }

            return null;
        }

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState) { }
    }
}

Is there any way where i can tell new relic agent to not add any headers for outgoing requests ?
Also is there any way where i can tell the .net core server to exclude certain headers from
outgoing http requests.
